# How to output date based on range of information?

Tags: excel

I'm struggling to find the answer I need because I'm not sure of the exact phrasing, so please bear with me if the question is a repeat or easily found. Below is the basic information I have and need output:

[image]

The data would be on different sheets in my final version, but this gives you an idea of what I'm after. I get that the range may have to be in different cells, but I'm not sure how to phrase a formula in the output cells that will give the desired result. The dates and ranges need to be manually added, and will not always be three dates, sometimes it'll just be one, so the range would be 1-25, with no data in the following cells.

I don't know how to code macros or use javascript, so if that's the only solution I may have to look at a manual solution.

Any help with an answer, or pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem with VLOOKUP() you have to do some changes in your "Range-Setting-Area"

Put the formula in B10 an copy down
(Maybe in your Excel-Version you have to replace semicolon with comma)

```
=VLOOKUP(A10;$C$2:$D$4;2;TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! So if I understand this correctly, this formula checks if the number in the Range matches the A column, then outputs the Date value if it does. If it doesn't, it populates with the one above?

Comment: Yes, your right. If it doesn‘t it populated the next smaler.